# Files not uploading due to unkown error using laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

- Laravel Version: 5.5

I have a problem when uploading a file. I have multiple files in the array, I am uploading these files two times in the same function for the first time I am checking pdf file version, and file dimensions this block of code works perfectly but in the second block of code I am again uploading these files for merging these files it gives me this error "**The file "A4.pdf" was not uploaded due to an unknown error**". When I remove the first block of code then the second block of code start working.I don't know where I did mistake, I have searched a lot but not found the answer.

This block of code checking pdf file version and dimensions.

```
$paper_size = array();
$del_files = array();
foreach ($files as $file) {

        $filename = time().date('m-d-y').$file->getClientOriginalName();

        $file->move(public_path().'/uploads/check_pdf_files/', $filename);

        $version = $this->pdfVersion(public_path().'/uploads/check_pdf_files/'.$filename);

        if($version > 1.5)
        {
            File::delete('public/uploads/check_pdf_files/'.$filename);

            return Response::json(" Your PDF file version is greater than 1.4 which is not compatible with our system, Please make it lower version.", 400);
        }

        $get_paper_size = $this->get_pdf_dimensions('public/uploads/check_pdf_files/'.$filename);

        $paper_size[] = $get_paper_size;
        $del_files[] = $filename;
    }

    if(round($paper_size[0]['width']) != round($paper_size[1]['width']))
    {
        foreach ($del_files as $del) 
        {
            File::delete('public/uploads/check_pdf_files/'.$del);
        }

        return Response::json(" Your Files dimensions is not matching please try with same dimensions.", 400);
    }
```

This block of code using for merging the files.

```
         $new_pdf_file = array();

         foreach ($request->file as $merge_file) 
            {
                $newFile_name = time().$merge_file->getClientOriginalName();


                $merge_file->move('public/uploads/', $newFile_name);

                $new_pdf_file[] = $newFile_name;
            }
            dd($new_pdf_file);

            $pdf = new \LynX39\LaraPdfMerger\PdfManage;

            foreach($new_pdf_file as $new)
            {
                $pdf->addPDF('public/uploads/dummy_uploads/'.$new, 'all');
            }

            $temp_name = time().$request->merge_name;

            $pdf->merge('file',base_path(). '/public/uploads/' . Auth::user()->email . '/'.$temp_name.'.pdf', 'P');

            foreach($new_pdf_file as $delete_new)
            {
                File::delete('public/uploads/dummy_uploads/'.$delete_new);
            }

            $user = DB::table('user_pdf_files')->insert([
                'user_files' => $request->merge_name.'.pdf',
                'filename' => $temp_name.'.pdf',
                'type' => $request->type[0],
                'user_id'    => Auth::user()->id,
            ]);

            Session::flash('success', 'Files Merged Successfully');
            return Response::json('success', 200);`
```

Comment: I think it could be due to the file size, check this: ; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 40M

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 40M

Comment: but in the first block of code, it's uploading why not in the second one, if I remove the first block of code then its start working.

Comment: If you move the file in the first code block, the file will not be present in the second code block. cause it's already moved to another location. hope that helps you

Answer (score 0):

You need the fully qualified path to where you want the files saved to. Anytime you are moving or copying a file, ensure that you are using [`public_path()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-public-path) with the relative path as a parameter. This function outputs the fully qualified path to the public folder. For example:

```
$merge_file->move(public_path('uploads'), $newFile_name);
```

This should be why the first code block is working vs. the second one. Not a very descriptive error, though!

Comment: still getting the same problem